# How do you copy from a rectangular source region to a non-rectangular/non-paralellogram destination region in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics

I know how to use the DrawImage() method of the Graphics object to copy from a rectangular source region to a rectangular destination region, and how to copy to a paralellogram region defined by a three-element Point[] array.

Is there any way in .NET to copy from a rectangular source region to a 4-sided non-rectangular destination region (which is defined by four arbitrary points)?

**Update**.  Here is some sample code that copies an image to a parallelogram region:

```
using (Graphic g = this.CreateGraphics())
{
    List<Point> pts = new List<Point>();
    pts.Add(new Point(0, 0));
    pts.Add(new Point(100, 0));
    pts.Add(new Point(10, 100));
    g.DrawImage(pbSource.Image, pts.ToArray());
}
```

If I add a fourth point, I get a "Not Implemented" exception.

**Update 2**.  It *is* possible to do this entirely in .NET:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a770d1e97f.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a770d1e97f.jpg)

but you have to do it yourself, pixel-by-pixel.  Graphics courtesy of [Jonbert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305223/jon-skeet-facts#309319).

Comment: Sorry, know only of the win32 method ;-)

Comment: @Gamecat: I'll take it. I'm a PInvoking fool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* possible to do this entirely in .NET:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a770d1e97f.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a770d1e97f.jpg)

but you have to do it yourself, pixel-by-pixel.  Graphics courtesy of [Jonbert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305223/jon-skeet-facts#309319).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there isn't a straightforward (built-in) way to do this kind of image transform in .NET.

If you look at [Anti Aliased Image Transformation (Aaform)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/Aaform.aspx) over on codeproject, you can download his sample in which there is a pure vb implementation of the concept (as well as a vb and c++ sample).

There is also [Anti-Grain Geometry](http://antigrain.com/), a free-to-use (for non-commercial) c++ graphics library and [a c# wrapper](http://www.creativedocs.net/devs/agg) for it.

Hope this helps.